# Remotely joining computer to domain using powershell and WMI

Tags: active-directory, powershell-remoting

For a CI/CD environment I am building a PowerShell script to create an new Hyper-V VM which is basically a clone of a 'base-vm'. This base-vm is not a member of the domain, it is a Windows workgroup member.

When trying to add the computer to the domain I have the following issue, the script displayed below works when run directly on the target machine which is the Hyper-V host (running under an administrative account) but not when being run from the build server (Jenkins).

The process is as shown in the following scheme:
[image: Jenkins deployment scheme]

And the script part which is failing is the following:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $remoteSession -Scriptblock {
    Rename-Computer -NewName $args[0] -Restart 
} -ArgumentList $vmSettings.ComputerName

Start-Sleep -s 30

$newVmRemoteSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $vmSettings.ComputerName -Credential $credentials

Invoke-Command -Session $newVmRemoteSession -Scriptblock {
    Add-Computer -Domainname myfunny.domain -Credential $args[0] -Restart
} -ArgumentList $domainAdminCredentials

Remove-PSSession $newVmRemoteSession
Remove-PSSession $remoteSession

Write-Host "Done creating new VM"
```

The `$remoteSession` variable contains a remote PowerShell session based on the local administrator crendentials.

The `$newVmRemoteSession` variable contains an remote session to the renamed virtual machine with the local administrator crendentials.

The error I recieve while running this script via a build-job:

> [base-vm] Connecting to remote server base-vm failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

The command which throws the exception is:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $newVmRemoteSession -Scriptblock {
    Add-Computer -Domainname myfunny.domain -Credential $args[0] -Restart
} -ArgumentList $domainAdminCredentials`
```

I have been looking for the solution for this problem, but I cannot find the error. First I thought it had to do with trusted relationships between the build server and the virtual machine but when I used WinRM to add that relationship the build still fails.

I used: `winrm s winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="*"}'` to add the relationship.

UPDATE: The other thing I did is running the script with the same user as the build server did. This gave me the same error as above. The strange thing is that the user is an local administrator on the server from which the script is being run and is also member of the 'remote management users' group on that server.

UPDATE2: I found out that the issue has to do with Kerberos versus Negotiate authentication. When running a script from a domain joined workstation the script runs under the Kerberos scheme by default and when run from a standalone workstation it runs under the Negotaite scheme, which needs an SPN for what I read from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378748(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: The error message offers some advice. Did you follow it? What were the results? Also, which statement exactly is throwing the error in the first place?

Comment: I have been looking for the solution for this problem, but I cannot find the error. First I thought it had to do with trusted relationships between the build server and the virtual machine but when I used winrm to add that relationship the build still fails.

I used: ` winrm s winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="*"}'` to add the relationship.

Comment: On your Jenkins host: did you check that a) the new name of the VM can be resolved to an IP address, and b) you can connect to port 5985 on the VM?

Comment: The Jenkins host does not access the new VM, the Hyper-V host does. And the error occurs before renaming, the script cannot access the 'base-vm' which is the template VM which has to be renamed. I will try adding a schematic overview for this setup.

Comment: Turns out that the issue is probably the following: 
When running locally I am in the domain as an user, but when running remotely the script is not running on a domain joined pc. I will check this out and come back on it.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384295(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computer was not accessible through the domain, so I used [CredSSP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb931352(v=vs.85).aspx) to connect to it. To enable credssp I had to run the enable-wsmancredssp commandlet on the client and server and had to use the gpedit.msc addin to configure access.

Answer (score 0):

You're right in that it's probably an auth issue.
PowerShell uses Kerberos for this stuff and is set up for domain joined stuff.
I think you were on the right lines with the trusted hosts addition...

There's an article at http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2016/01/25/enabling-powershell-remoting-with-ntlm.aspx, which explains how to set it up and uses slightly different syntax to what you've described. Maybe try that?

Comment: I assumed that winrm s winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="*"}' did the trick for that. I will look into the link you posted.